# What is electron hole? Isn't it just an absence of electron?

Tags: electrons

I was reading Wikipedia article about [impact ionization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_ionization) and there's something in it's definition that makes me wonder:

> Impact ionization is the process in a material by which one energetic charge carrier can lose energy by the creation of other charge carriers. For example, in semiconductors, an electron (**or hole**) with enough kinetic energy **can knock a bound electron out of its bound state** (in the valence band) and promote it to a state in the conduction band, creating an electron-hole pair.

Isn't "electron hole" concept to express lack of electron? I thought it is similar concept to "darkness", which is lack of light.

And if it is just a lack of electron, how can "empty space" knock out an electron? If it's "just a hole" (there's nothing there), then it have no mass, no real energy... how can it even affect another electron in such way that it will be pushed away?

I would be glad if someone could explain to me what really electron hole really is, and if it's not just an absence of something, then what is it?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98437/

Comment: And  physics.stackexchange.com/q/98971