# Electronics and junctions

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

In a p-n junction, is it only the electrons that move from the n-type part to the p-type part in order to create a depletion region or is it the movement of both electrons and holes from the n-type and the p-type respectively? If it is so, then the whole idea of a depletion region seems flawed, considering how there is a net movement of electrons and holes both. Can someone explain?

Comment: I think the concept of holes may help you to get rid of your confusion.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98437/why-absence-of-electron-is-called-hole .

Comment: Holes are absence of electrons. When one electron in a region move to the other, a hole is generated there.

Comment: Thank u it was a helpful article